# MYSQL: combine 2 count sql group by year

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 Table with same structure, each of it i use the almost the same sql to select and SUM.

SQL1:

```
SELECT YEAR, SUM(GENERATION) AS generationA, SUM(TRANSMISSION) AS transmissionA
FROM tableA 
WHERE YEAR BETWEEN '2013' AND  '2016' 
AND POWER_PLANT_ID = 'ABC1' 
AND STATUS = 'V' 
AND transmission IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY YEAR
```

SQL2:

```
SELECT YEAR, SUM(GENERATION) AS generationB, SUM(TRANSMISSION) AS transmissionB
FROM tableB 
WHERE YEAR BETWEEN '2013' AND  '2016' 
AND POWER_PLANT_ID = 'ABC1' 
AND STATUS = 'V' 
AND transmission IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY YEAR
```

how to combine this 2 sql to group by its year?

Comment: what's your expected output? Please provide some sample input and expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
select year, sum(generationA) as generationA, sum(transmissionA) as transmissionA from
(
SELECT YEAR, SUM(GENERATION) AS generationA, SUM(TRANSMISSION) AS transmissionA
FROM tableA 
WHERE YEAR BETWEEN '2013' AND  '2016' 
AND POWER_PLANT_ID = 'ABC1' 
AND STATUS = 'V' 
AND transmission IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY YEAR
union all
SELECT YEAR, SUM(GENERATION) AS generationB, SUM(TRANSMISSION) AS transmissionB
FROM tableB 
WHERE YEAR BETWEEN '2013' AND  '2016' 
AND POWER_PLANT_ID = 'ABC1' 
AND STATUS = 'V' 
AND transmission IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY YEAR
) as t
group by YEAR
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join

```
  SELECT 
          a.YEAR
        , SUM(a.GENERATION) AS generationA
        , SUM(a.TRANSMISSION) AS transmissionA
        , SUM(b.GENERATION) AS generationB
        , SUM(b.TRANSMISSION) AS transmissionB
  FROM tableA  as a 
  LEFT JOIN tableB as b on  (a.YEAR = b.year 
                              and a..POWER_PLANT_ID = b.POWER_PLANT_ID 
                              and a.STATUS = b.STATUS
                               and a.transmission = b.transmission)
  WHERE a.YEAR BETWEEN '2013' AND  '2016' 
  AND a.POWER_PLANT_ID = 'ABC1' 
  AND a.STATUS = 'V' 
  AND a.transmission IS NOT NULL 
  GROUP BY a.YEAR
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below script,if you wanted to sum up the the result sets by grouping with year.

```
SELECT YEAR,SUM(GENERATION) generation,SUM(TRANSMISSION)TRANSMISSION
FROM
(SELECT YEAR, GENERATION , TRANSMISSION 
FROM tableA 
WHERE YEAR BETWEEN '2013' AND  '2016' 
AND POWER_PLANT_ID = 'ABC1' 
AND STATUS = 'V' 
AND transmission IS NOT NULL 


UNION ALL 

SELECT YEAR, GENERATION, TRANSMISSION
FROM tableB 
WHERE YEAR BETWEEN '2013' AND  '2016' 
AND POWER_PLANT_ID = 'ABC1' 
AND STATUS = 'V' 
AND transmission IS NOT NULL )AS t
GROUP BY YEAR
```